# magento 2: getAttributeText() return wrong value

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I'm trying to get Custom Attribute by getAttributeText(), i've 3 store with 3 different url
So when i use that function, 2 of my store return "no", and 1 return "yes", i don't know how to fix this or any idea what is cause
Please help, thanks you guys :(


So here is how i set up in admin:
[image]

As you can see, right now, i config it to "no", but 2 of my store working fine (return "no"), and another store is not working well (return "yes")
So here is the code:

> ..\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $dailydealhelper=$this->helper('Smartwave\Dailydeals\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <?php if($block->getRequest()->getParam('dailydealproduct') || $dailydealhelper->isDealProduct($_product->getId())) : ?>
       <?php $productSku=$_product->getSku(); ?>
    <input type="text" id="todate" value="<?php echo $dailydealhelper->getDailydealToDate($productSku); ?>" style="display:none;" >
    <input type="text" style="display: none;" id="fromdate" value="<?php echo $dailydealhelper->getDailydealFromDate($productSku); ?>">
    <p id="countdown"></p>
    <div class="sw-dailydeal-wrapper">
      <div class="sw-dailydeal">
        <?php if($block->getRequest()->getParam('dailydealproduct')) :?>
            <p id="expired"></p> 
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="countdowncontainer" style="display:none;">
            <span class="dailydeal-label">
                <?php echo __('Offer Ends In:'); ?>
            </span>
            <span class="number-wrapper">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <span class="number day"><p id="countdown_days"></p></span>
                <div class="caption"><?php echo __('Days'); ?></div>
            </span>

            <span class="number-wrapper">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <span class="number hour"><p id="countdown_hours"></p></span>
                <div class="caption"><?php echo __('Hours'); ?></div>
            </span>

            <span class="number-wrapper">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <span class="number min"><p id="countdown_minutes"></p></span>
                <div class="caption"><?php echo __('Minutes'); ?></div>
            </span>

            <span class="number-wrapper">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <span class="number sec"><p id="countdown_seconds"></p></span>
                <div class="caption"><?php echo __('Seconds'); ?></div>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php 
    $is_saleable = $_product->getAttributeText('is_saleable');
    if ($is_saleable) {
      $is_saleable = trim($is_saleable," ");
      $is_saleable = strtolower($is_saleable);
    }

    $request_quote = $_product->getAttributeText('request_quote');
    if ($request_quote) {
      $request_quote = trim($request_quote," ");
      $request_quote = strtolower($request_quote);
    }
    var_dump($request_quote); exit;
```

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are getting the correct values into two stores not only the last one.

maybe you are missed to set **request_quote** NO in your product

follow below screenshot. switch to every store and check your request_quote option value.

[image]

Comment: Oh man, you are so true, thanks you for this :) saved alot of time debugging, thanks you :)

Comment: Welcome, bro  :)